# How can we calculate the generalized gradient of $L^2\ni x\mapsto a\min(x(s),by(t))$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $(T,\mathcal T,\tau)$ be a measure space, $a,b\ge0$, $s,t\in T$ and $$f(x):=a\min(x(s),bx(t))\;\;\;\text{for }x\in L^2(\tau).$$

> How can we calculate the [generalized gradient](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272585/1-s2.0-S0001870800X02502/1-s2.0-0001870881900323/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDncC3kz2PE7TC8KlgxOrKGXZboogmvjd%2FWr3oL3dR8TgIhAO8c6uJpTlXb9BVyFg091nHZAVaJXBNMXIiwuBN1mXXyKuMDCIn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igx0g%2BgnzEdovUHHPU8qtwPLOK0uSYKkcP7Epkqzua2wNo0VVHHF379AxjWXRGpFY2cM081ElPcXHr1WZQtCbSIGpdbavxbfPcTqlJuYSevJkksJT%2FlTmwcNxrSw9bpWhjw2DhX%2B3fqk1GRnZ38Lsvfcqhrlt2rNspAWIQe%2F93eD4Sii8P%2BZFbMjgkDuvISlsym0wzORJ%2B%2FTxeH5w4mdIq4gMQ1Vbgw6LV%2FBcxx5sydeS9Vyd3PFh5ZMl5H5uH71ZBRO2gLXBK2RHLGHk5oipEf%2B5EPIrNfnu2eYRQnFFmxrrD5gqAO1ZVhUh%2BrDgpHjNV6XqvSRHFOH7F6LqVJv%2FOlW5UhnrXfewMQVprtXQ8054GHH3WEgx%2FqWQML%2F957vcYRFPrVCrm8VTb7%2B3AtsY8rOcN%2F00%2F11Zg6wd1LYJR8iG714rurZzbEWqOlLEzoJaPNTLP1vwRBkb%2B91%2FLVaT9CjSqULYvMaTldbq%2FMqney8QmpTo6mUQeqYwD2b%2BNk8GXYpIPeKBLy2Mrtnub8BuznaLqv%2FVSBUtdUuqFAPjIc90dsf15KvkFpuriZN4IZb3OJh%2B5Fi%2Bgw29Oa9WF%2BA8K3OfD%2FTEhj8MOG6h%2BwFOrMB1oE6S0%2FJS%2BJ%2BPfsR2be%2F8gKCc4EDj8IVnr%2BZuSOMvbIhoxhywZqpXDvGS8MNgJv4axqZ2OL2CSBcjs7SfOazxHzmcRBqL9veYQi5e0sUL0F6X%2BoD%2FRukrdisUZMuNXF%2FDDE%2BMIcuefsmOHVTd0DR1hUuZTSZi%2B5Oqj%2BSTqhE6YrwX6Ewtx%2BgV1dJMJf91cQlT7wEZU%2FKvVYrOrDE6d4IkUniYnNnIW11n5%2B4metofUYDjhY%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190918T084923Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZ5D4I5AJ%2F20190918%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3794a3cd286dac45255e2a59e02bd53c8def7f8f6c193d95480e0f6d7be8fb67&hash=33ba1fda1dfb5fb50522e5f436a6cd1f37852dec06e1854e80f94e5019494ea5&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0001870881900323&tid=spdf-d0e3327f-85c2-421d-a45c-8e6f4ab0cf5d&sid=b376c27b7e56944aa038dc543f341a6f5a61gxrqa&type=client) $\partial_Cf(x)$ of $f$ at $x\in L^2(\tau)$?

We may note that $2\min(u,v)=u+v-|u-v|$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb R$. Now the only point on which $\mathbb R\ni u\mapsto|u|$ is not differentiable (in the classical sense) is $0$, but the generalized gradient at $0$ is easily seen to be $[-1,1]$. Moreover, $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\ni u\mapsto|u|$ is continuously differentiable and the generalized gradient at $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is simply $\{x/|x|\}$. This knowledge should be helpful. However, I'm new to this topic and have no idea how to tackle the problem.

**EDIT**: As [Iosif Pinelis pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/341920/91890), we need to assume that the singletons in $(T,\mathcal T,\tau)$ are measurable and admit positive measure to ensure that $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$
The notion of the generalized gradient, as defined in Clarke's paper linked in your question, is applicable only to Lipschitz functions. In general, depending on your measure space, your function $f$ will not be Lipschitz, because the evaluation functional $L^2(\tau)\ni x\mapsto\de_s(x):=x(s)$ for $s\in T$ will not be Lipschitz in general. Therefore, the generalized gradient of your function $f$ will be undefined in general. In particular, it will be undefined if your measure $\tau$ is non-atomic.

---

However, we have $\|x\|_2\ge\tau(\{r\})^{1/2}|x(r)|$ for all $r\in T$. So, if $\tau(\{r\})>0$, then the evaluation functional $\de_r$ is bounded and hence Lipschitz. So, assuming now that $\tau(\{s\})>0$ and $\tau(\{t\})>0$, we see that your nonlinear function(al)
\begin{equation*}
 f=\min(\de_s,b\de_t)
\end{equation*}
is Lipschitz. (I am assuming $a=1$, without loss of generality.) 
Moreover, then the generalized (upper) directional derivative of $f$ at $x\in L^2(\tau)$ in the direction $v\in L^2(\tau)$ is 
\begin{multline*}
 f^0(x;v):=\limsup_{y\to x,h\downarrow0}\frac{f(y+hv)-f(y)}h \\ 
 =\left\{\begin{aligned}
 v(s)&\text{ if }x(s)<bx(t), \\
 bv(t)&\text{ if }x(s)>bx(t), \\
  \max[v(s),bv(t)] &\text{ if }x(s)=bx(t); 
 \end{aligned}\right. \tag{1}
\end{multline*}
see details on this at the end of this answer; here I am using the (somewhat strange to me) notation $f^0(x;v)$ from the linked paper by Clarke.

So, the generalized gradient is $\{\de_s\}$ if $x(s)<bx(t)$ and $\{b\de_t\}$ if $x(s)>bx(t)$.

Consider now the case $x(s)=bx(t)$:

Consider first the subcase $s\ne t$. We have 
$$\max(v_s,bv_t)\ge Av_s+Bv_t\quad\text{for all real }v_s,v_t
$$
iff $0\le A\le1$ and $B=(1-A)b$. So, if $x(s)=bx(t)$ and $s\ne t$, then the generalized gradient is the set of all linear functionals $\ell$ given by the formula 
$$\ell(v)=Av(s)+(1-A)bv(t)\quad\text{for }v\in L^2(\tau)
$$
with $A\in[0,1]$.

If $s=t$, $\tau(\{t\})>0$, and $x(t)=bx(t)$ (that is, either $b=1$ or $x(t)=0$), then 
$f^0(x;v)=\max[v(t),bv(t)]$ and the generalized gradient is the set of all linear functionals $\ell$ given by the formula 
$$\ell(v)=Av(t)\quad\text{for }v\in L^2(\tau)
$$
with $A\in[\min(1,b),\max(1,b)]$.

**Details on (1):** If for a function $x\in L^2(\tau)$ with $\tau(\{s\})>0$ and $\tau(\{t\})>0$ we have $x(s)<bx(t)$, and a function $y\in L^2(\tau)$ is close enough to $x$, and real $h>0$ is small enough, then $y(s)+hv(s)<by(t)+bhv(t)$ and $y(s)<by(t)$, so that 
$f(y+hv)-f(y)=y(s)+hv(s)-y(s)=hv(s)$, 
and hence $f^0(x;v)=v(s)$, in the case $x(s)<bx(t)$. 
Similarly, $f^0(x;v)=bv(t)$ in the case $x(s)>bx(t)$.

To complete the proof of (1), it remains to consider the case $x(s)=bx(t)$. Then the function $x\in L^2(\tau)$ can be however closely approximated by functions $\check x$ and $\hat x$ in $L^2(\tau)$ such that $\check x(s)<b\check x(t)$ and $\hat x(s)>b\hat x(t)$, so that, by what has just been shown, $f^0(\check x;v)=v(s)$ and $f^0(\hat x;v)=bv(t)$. Letting now $\check x\to x$ and $\hat x\to x$ and using the upper semincontinuity of $f^0(\cdot;\cdot)$ (which is item 4 of the list on page 54 in the linked paper by Clarke), we conclude that 
\begin{equation*}
 f^0(x;v)\ge\max[v(s),bv(t)]. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, for any $y\in L^2(\tau)$ and real $h>0$, 
\begin{multline*}
 f(y+hv)-f(y)=\min[y(s)+hv(s),by(t)+bhv(t)]-\min[y(s),by(t)] \\ 
 \le\max[hv(s),bhv(t)],
\end{multline*}
by the inequality $\min[z_1,w_1]-\min[z_2,w_2]\le\max[z_1-z_2,w_1-w_2]$ for real $z_1,w_1,z_2,w_2$. 
So, 
\begin{equation*}
 f^0(x;v)\le\max[v(s),bv(t)]. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Finally, by (2) and (3), we get $f^0(x;v)=\max[v(s),bv(t)]$, in the case $x(s)=bx(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there useful sufficient conditions on $\tau$ ensuring that the evaluation maps are locally Lipschitz (or even continuously differentiable)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Yes, the necessary and sufficient condition for the evaluation map at $s$ to be Lipshcitz is that $\tau(\{s\})>0$.

Comment: I see, thanks. It's my fault that I didn't check whether $f$ at least satisfies the necessary conditions. However, I'm still interested in the question under the additional assumption you provided.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I have added the calculation of the generalized gradient in the case when $\tau$ does not have atoms at $s$ or $t$.

Comment: That's great, thank you. What can we do in the diagonal case $s=t$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I have added the case $s=t$ as well.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I'll try to look at that other question as well.

Comment: Thanks, once again. BTW: My motivation for the question was this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/339511/91890. Can we utilize the result here to answer the other question? See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3360750/47771 for a situation which is closer to the situation here as well.

Comment: One last query for this question: (a) How exactly did you obtain the result for the directional derivative? (b) It's clear to me that if $\{t\}\in\mathcal T$ and $\tau(\{t\})>0$, then $$|x(t)|=\frac1{\tau(\{t\})}\int_{\{t\}}|x|\:{\rm d}\tau$$ for all $x\in L^1(\tau)$. Thus, assuming that $\tau$ is *finite*, $L^p(\tau)\ni x\mapsto x(\{t\})$ is a bounded linear functional by Hölder's inequality for all $p\ge1$. In particular, it is (globally) Lipschitz continuous. But what do we do, when $\tau$ is not finite? I guess we need at least something like local compactness or am I wrong?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I have provided the details you requested, and also a correction: the previous formulas were good only for the more difficult case $x(s)=bx(t)$; the considerations are quite a bit simpler if $x(s)<bx(t)$ or $x(s)>bx(t)$.

Comment: Thanks, once again. Did you had a chance to take a look at the other two questions?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I have briefly looked at those questions, but at the moment I don't have good ideas about them yet.

Comment: In light of the equation $(\ast)$ in the screenshot I've provided in the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3360750/47771, shouldn't we be able to use the result of this question?

Comment: (BTW, we can conclude that in the case $x(s)=bx(t)$, $$\partial_Cf(x)=\{A\delta_s+(1-A)b\delta_t:A\in[0,1]\},$$ no matter whether $s=t$ or not, right? And it's worth to mention that your argument should still hold if we replace $L^2(\tau)$ by $L^p(\tau)$, $p\in[1,\infty]$.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I agree with your latter comment. Concerning the previous one, I think that may go beyond the usual framework for MO answers and possibly require a full-blown paper. Even for the much simpler question posted on this page, the answer with complete details is quite long.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't necessarily need an answer with all the details, but an outline or sketch how one could proceed. (I could imagine that a consideration in the spirit of Example 10.49 of Clarke's book might work.)

Comment: I've tried to figure out as much as possible in the special case $I=\{1,2\}$ and asked a separate question for how we can proceed: https://mathoverflow.net/q/342173/91890. Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: Just worked out the left details (https://mathoverflow.net/q/342173/91890) and noticed that $w$ disappears when we differentiate the integral function. So, it seems like this approach is of no help to determine the maximizing $w$. Maybe you can take a look if I missed something crucial.

Comment: interchange of minimization and integration given in Theorem 14.60 of the book *Variational Analysis* by Rockafellar and ‎Wets (see also Theorem 2.1 in  [this paper](https://cermics.enpc.fr/cermics-rapports-recherche/2006/CERMICS-2006/CERMICS-2006-321.pdf)) might be useful. Do you think it is applicable here?

Comment: Give me one last shot: $x\mapsto x^+:=\max(0,x)$ can be smoothly approximated by $x\mapsto p_\alpha(x):=x+\frac1\alpha\ln\left(1+e^{-\alpha x}\right)$, $\alpha>0$. We could use this to approximate $x\mapsto|x|=x^++(-x)^+$ and hence to approximate $(a,b)\mapsto\min(a,b)=\frac12(a+b-|a-b|)$. We could solve the optimization problem with an accordingly modified objective function. If $w^{(\alpha)}$ is the resulting maximizer, how would it be related to the maximizer $w$ of the actual objective function? (If you know it, this might be an answer to one of the other questions.)

Comment: I was able to reduce my problem to a smooth optimization problem. It would be great if you could took a look https://mathoverflow.net/q/344621/91890.